# adding openCV modules after installation in linux (fedora)

Tags: linux, opencv, fedora

i have opencv 2.4 installed in my machine (fedora). i want to add `nonfree` module to openCV because of SIFT features. 
how should i add this module without making and installing the whole opencv pachage again ?

Comment: You installed opencv from the yum ? the module is most probably already there isn't it?

Comment: i didnt install it, the opencv is already installed in my machine by someone else and it doesn't contain that module.

Comment: @remi, would you know, if yum would actually install that module? fedora being notoriously picky about nonfree stuff and all